# Visual Basic has stopped working

Tags: vb6

I new in vb6.0 technology ,having two scenarios as below

1) I installed VB 6.0 and run the program it gives me an Error "Visual Basic has stopped working." and the same below message is display into clip board

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: vb6.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.81.76
  Application Timestamp:    3592011f
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_3da4
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdadb
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 000c283b
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 3da4
  Additional Information 2: 3da43af88e0567c295fedcade1d2a40c
  Additional Information 3: d947
  Additional Information 4: d9474a8c4482358d739380510e1335ec
```

This things I have done my development PC

2) these the same thing done with same code run on different computer it run successfully without any error so that I made the .exe of my project and try to run on my PC but above error arises.

don't know what goes wrong with this ?

Comment: is quite possible that some API/DLL functions are not compatible in another pc, and you development pc has all dll and assemblies register, so is same OS version ? if are you trying run on vista, windows 7 use Right-Click on VB6.exe icon, select Properties option and then Compatibility Tab. Do check on "Run this program in compatibility mode for : Windows XP (Service Pack 3) ". Good Luck!!

Comment: I will post as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some API/DLL functions are not compatible in another pc, and you development pc has all dll and assemblies register, so is same OS version ? if are you trying run on vista, windows 7 use Right-Click on VB6.exe icon, select Properties option and then Compatibility Tab. Do check on "Run this program in compatibility mode for : Windows XP (Service Pack 3) ".

Comment: i need to ask one thing is that as per you told i have done the changes it work fine but when i open the file from fileopen dialog 1st time it render the image successfully and the same i try to load new image from the fileopen dialog the "Visual Basic has stopped working" message pop up and application get crash

Comment: Can you give more details, about your scenary ? what version OS are you running ? 32 or 64 bits ? Do you have a Visual Basic 6 Sp6 Installed ?

Comment: vb6.0 SP6, Windows 7:- 32 bits 
scenario picture box , and Load Image Button:- when I first time run the application and load image it works but when i try to load the another image into picture box then application is crashed.

Comment: this is a weird question .. How to big is your image ? Did you release Image object when try to load second image ?

I found this VB's back-buffer implementation uses a Device Dependant Bitmap (DDB) to store the image data, which is quite limited in 
how large it can be made.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/znas-dERc-g/ut3mQNzHQX0J